# Interactive command for inserting the string returned by a function

Tags: emacs, elisp

When evaluating elisp symbolic expressions with (eval-last-sexp), bound to C-x C-e, I can just type C-u before that command to insert the result of the expression into the current buffer.

Is there some equivalent to that when calling functions interactively? For example, if I want to insert the string returned by (emacs-version) into the current-buffer, how would I do that? M-x emacs-version only shows the string in the minibuffer and typing C-u before M-x emacs-version won't work either.

If there is no such equivalent, what would be the easiest way to insert a string returned by a function without first having to type the function down before evaluating it?

UPDATE:

C-u M-x emacs-version **does** actually work. My mistake. But it does not work for emacs-uptime. How come it doesn't work for that one?

Comment: `C-u M-x emacs-version` does work in Emacs 24, as does `C-u M-:`. This feature is also present in Emacs 23 (which is the currently released version). What version are you using?

Comment: Oh, that is true `C-u M-x emacs-version` works for me too. I hadn't tried that one, only with `emacs-uptime`, my mistake. However, why doesn't `C-u M-x emacs-uptime` work if it works with `emacs-version`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`emacs-uptime` was implemented to output the result only to minibuffer

```
(defun emacs-uptime (&optional format)
  (interactive)
  (let ((str
         (format-seconds (or format "%Y, %D, %H, %M, %z%S")
                         (float-time
                          (time-subtract (current-time) before-init-time)))))
    (if (called-interactively-p 'interactive)
        (message "%s" str)
      str)))
```

`emacs-version` has the following code which prints output if called with `C-u`

```
(if here
        (insert version-string)
      (if (called-interactively-p 'interactive)
          (message "%s" version-string)
        version-string))
```

If you want to print the result of a particular command (e.g. `emacs-uptime`) you can wrap it to `insert` result into the current buffer (similar to `emacs-version`).

However, I don't know a generic solution - how to output the result of any Emacs command.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun my-insert-command-value (command)
  "Insert the return value of the command."
  (interactive "*C(insert) M-x ")
  (print (call-interactively command) (current-buffer)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`C-u M-x pp-eval-expression RET (emacs-uptime) RET`

*"Evaluate Emacs-Lisp sexp EXPRESSION, and pretty-print its value.
With a prefix arg, insert the value into the current buffer at point.
 With a negative prefix arg, if the value is a string, then insert it
 into the buffer without double-quotes (`"')."*

See [pp+.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/pp%2b.el).